# Firing Laravel 5.4 event is causing problems in localhost

Tags: php, laravel, events, pusher, broadcasting

First of all Hello , 
i have a kinda of problem that i cannot manage  . 
am posting an ajax request like the following

```
  <script>



    $(document).ready(function(){


        $(document).on('keydown' , '.message_input', function(e){



            var token = $('input[name=_token]').val(); 
            var msg  = $(this).val(); 
            var element = $(this) ; 
            var ul = element.parent().parent().find('ul'); 
            var authenticated_user_id = $(this).attr('data-auth-id'); 
            var user_id = $(this).attr('data-to-user-id'); 
            var conversation_id = $(this).attr('data-conversation-id'); 

            if(!msg == '' && e.keyCode == 13  && !e.shiftKey){


                                 $.ajaxSetup({
                                      headers: {
                                          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                                      }
                                  });


                                $.ajax({



                                    url : "{{ url("$lang/post_message_test")}}" ,
                                    method : 'POST',
                                    cache: false, 
                                    dataType:'JSON', 
                                    data: {   msg:msg  , authenticated_user_id:authenticated_user_id  , user_id:user_id , conversation_id: conversation_id , _token:token   },

                                    success:function(data){

                                       // my logic  
                                    }
                                });


                                return false ;    


            } 

        });

    });

</script>
```

this will take with a chat controller and specific function called  postMessage

it has a structure like the following

```
public function postMessage(Request $request ){


    if($request->ajax()){




        /** data coming from our post request with an elegant way */
        $authenticated_user_id = $request->get('authenticated_user_id'); 
        $user_id = $request->get('user_id'); 
        $conversation_id = $request->get('conversation_id');

        $msg = $request->get('msg');




        // find user image  
        $user = User::find($authenticated_user_id) ; 
        $image = asset('uploads/users/').'/'.$user->profileImage ; 




        $name = '' ; 

        if($user->userType == 'doctor'){

            $name = $user->doctorName ;
        }else{
            $name = $user->headPersonName  ; 
        }





        $message  = new Message ; 

        $message->sender_id = $authenticated_user_id ; 
        $message->receiver_id = $user_id ; 
        $message->conversation_id = $conversation_id ; 
        $message->message = $msg ; 
        $message->is_read = 'not_read'  ; 

        if($message->save()){

            $msg=Message::where('id',$message->id)
            ->select('id','message','sender_id','receiver_id','created_at')
            ->with('sender')
            ->with('receiver')
            ->first();






         $sender_name =  $msg->sender->name ; 
         $sender_image =  $msg->sender->profileImage ; 

          $dt = Carbon::now(); 

                $message_date  = $dt->diffForHumans() ; 






           event(new MessageWasRecieved( $user_id , $message->message , $image  , $authenticated_user_id , $name ));

           return Response::json([
                                    'status'=>'success'   , 
                                    'message'=>$msg->message , 
                                    'user_id'=>$user_id , 
                                    'auth_id'=>Auth::user()->id , 
                                    'image'=>$sender_image , 
                                    'name'=>$sender_name 


                                ]);



        }else{

             return Response::json([
                                    'status'=>'error'   , 



                                ]);
        }






    }


}
```

in that simple logic when it reaches to event function , it should trigger that event  and in javascript am waiting to listen to this event .

what really happens  is that after posting to this url post_message_test 
that what happens in network tab  instead of returning a status code of 200 it gives me a 302 status (  check image below  )

[image]

and call another url called campaign ( this is a url found also in my project  ) . i have tried all possible cautions  , i terrible checked my code and am sure of every thing is working perfect

so what is causing that and i hope i could described my problem correct
thanks

Answer (score 0):

> The status code 302 means a redirection! There is more than one
>   explanation for this, but often it is due to a route protected by the
>   auth middleware while the user is not connected!

To communicate with laravel by  XHR request **the best way** to do this is to use Laravel Passport ( [link here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport) )! I already met this kind of problem! This problem is that Laravel when it receives a request ajax it checked if in the headers there is the 'Authorization' header otherwise it redirects the user because for him he has no access token

**How to install Laravel Passport ?**

- with composer run : 
  `composer require laravel/passport`
- Then run : `php artisan migrate` to migrate passport Tables

**Configuration**

- Go to Config/auth.php and change the api driver to passpor

  ```
  'api' => [
      'driver' => 'passport',
      'provider' => 'users',
  ],
  ```

  - Finally add HasApiTokens traits in your User Model and Passport::routes() in your AuthServicePovider Class : method boot()

Comment: Okay , hence my request is ajax  , i returned it all      {"msg":"fdfdsfsdd dfsdfd","authenticated_user_id":"1","user_id":"2","conversation_id":"4","_token":"B3jfy7nOHMcUnebqCFJxgfX4qgl37wZyYyWdFTyc"} this is the request->all()

Comment: when you put dd () at the beginning of your postMethd you get this result?

Comment: To communicate with laravel by  XHR request the best way to do this is to use Laravel Passport! I already met this kind of problem! This problem is that Laravel when he receives a request ajax it checked if in the headers there is the header 'Authorization' otherwise it redirects the user because for him it has no access token - il edit my answer and i add Laravel Password Link!